# Affinity Propagatiomh in julia with the Clustering pkg

Tags: julia, cluster-analysis

I would like to use the Affinity Propagation algorithm from the Clustering pkg in Julia.
I have a colletection of n points with m variables. I created a mxn array but i would like to know what is the S input in the function affinityprop(S::DenseMatrix{T}; ...)

The python sklearn implementation seems to take the mxn array as input.

Comment: Hey, I can't give a full answer right now but here is an example which uses the affinity propogation on Word2Vec. It's fully self-contained so you should be able to just grab the packages and run it, and in doing so see exactly how it's used. If I get the time I might come back with a full answer, but hopefully this is enough to get it done. http://ucidatascienceinitiative.github.io/IntroToJulia/Html/ClusteringSolutions

Comment: Thanks! It is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it expects an **affinity matrix**.

But clearly there is a lack of documentation. You should file a bug report that asks for proper **documentation** to be included with Clustering.jl